# Showing locations on map and list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have some coordinates and some data about them inserted in database table. I want to show the info in a list and show the locations as markers on a map.

How can I relate list item to the corresponding marker on the map. like when I hover the mouse on a row in the list, the marker showing the location of that item on the map bounces or changes the color and the other way around; I mean hovering the mouse on a marker, highlights the row describing that marker.

I have something like [Homestay](https://www.homestay.com/) search results in mind

currently I`m using syncfusion map and a repeater to generate the list but I could change that if you could suggest me a better option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with syncfusion, but conceptually, I think what you want to do is to create a relationship between markers and list items.

Here is a pretty generic solution that you can (hopefully) modify to fit what you are doing:

```js
const locations = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.map-location'));

/**
 * Gets the location ID from the DOM element's data-location-id
 * this is how we have chosen to associate markers with details
 */
function getElemLocationID(elem) {
  return elem.getAttribute('data-location-id');
}

/**
 * Returns an array containing a marker and details element,
 * based on their shared locationID
 */
function getLocationElementsFromID(locationID, locations) {
  const linkedLocationElements = locations.filter((location) => {
    let compareID = getElemLocationID(location);
    return compareID === locationID;
  });

  return linkedLocationElements;
}

function handleMouseOver(elements) {
  elements.map((elem) => elem.classList.add('highlighted'));
}

function handleMouseOut(elements) {
  elements.map((elem) => elem.classList.remove('highlighted'));
}

/**
 * Sets up the mouse events on the map-location elements
 */
function linkListToMarkers(locations) {
  locations.map((location) => {
    location.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
      const locationID = getElemLocationID(e.currentTarget);
      const locationElements = getLocationElementsFromID(locationID, locations);
      handleMouseOver(locationElements);
    });
    location.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
      const locationID = getElemLocationID(e.currentTarget);
      const locationElements = getLocationElementsFromID(locationID, locations);
      handleMouseOut(locationElements);
    });
  });
}

linkListToMarkers(locations);
```

```css
.marker {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #cccccc;
}

.marker.highlighted {
  border: 3px solid magenta;
}

.details {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
}

.details.highlighted {
  color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU427.png" data-location-id="location-1" class="map-location marker" />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU427.png" data-location-id="location-2" class="map-location marker" />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU427.png" data-location-id="location-3" class="map-location marker" />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU427.png" data-location-id="location-4" class="map-location marker" />

<ul>
  <li data-location-id="location-1" class="map-location details">Location 1</li>
  <li data-location-id="location-2" class="map-location details">Location 2</li>
  <li data-location-id="location-3" class="map-location details">Location 3</li>
  <li data-location-id="location-4" class="map-location details">Location 4</li>
</ul>
```